# How can I use a very simple calendar/calendarview in my project?

Tags: android, calendar

Maybe it's a duplicate of an asked question here, but I was browsing in the last couple of hours and did not find the solution. 
I would like to implement a calendar, or just use the calendarview, but I do not really need adding events. I only need one thing, if I click on a date, I want to save the date into a variable, or for simplicity, just log it. So if I click on 5.april 2012, a string should contain this date. What would be way better, if I just get a number like 20120405 in this case.

I found some codes, examples, but none of them worked or somehow never managed to implement it. Could you help me out somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way to implement your needs is to use an external (lightweight) datepicker lib.

Here is a [great example](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/) of what you can find.

EDIT :

[I found this](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/). It's a calendar view that allows you to pick a date.

Comment: It's not a datepicker what I need.I would like to have a calender where I can choose from dates.

Comment: Yes this was one calendar I managed to make it work, but somehow it appears on my screen very badly.  Half of the calendar is slipped out of the screen.

Comment: Wow, i found a very nice one for this!!

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

Comment: one more [android-calendar-view](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what what you are looking for. This page tells you how to use calendar view

[How to use calender view](https://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/wiki/HowToUse)